# Auto-login looks strange

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-accounts

On the Trilogy sites, the auto-login thing goes over any notification bar and also goes down pretty far. On Gaming at least, it seems to append itself to the notification bar and it is also poorly padded so it's hard to notice.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking into this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we discovered what this is, and the fix should be deployed soon.